# How to check if Property exists in JSON and its value is true also

Tags: jquery

I have got a JSON as follows

```
{
    "name": "mark",
    "age": 35,
    "isActive": true
}
```

I need to check if the Property isActive  exists and it is true also

I have tried as below its woring ,but wanted to ask  is there any better way of doing than below

```
var test = {
    "name": "mark",
    "age": 35,
    "isActive": true
}

if(test.isActive && test.isActive==true)
{
alert('yes')
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/54440/

Comment: `test.isActive` is sufficient already

Comment: Define 'better'. What about `if(test.isActive && test.isActive==true)` isn't good enough? It's one line of code. Is it not a fast enough execution time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use json built in function called "hasOwnProperty()" to check this. PLease try like below it is working fine.

```
var test = {
    "name": "mark",
    "age": 35,
    "isActive": true
}

if(test.hasOwnProperty("isActive") && test.isActive===true){
    alert('yes');
}else{
   alert("no");
}
```

Comment: ```hasOwnProperty``` is exactly what author wants

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` has absolutely nothing to do with json which is a test data transfer format.  hasOwnProperty is an Object  protocol method

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
if (test.isActive === true)
```

If the property doesn't exist, the value of `this.isActive` will be `undefined`, which isn't equal to `true`.

Use `===` to get strict type checking, so it won't coerce other types and give a false result.

If the property always contains a boolean when it exists, you can just use:

```
if (test.isActive)
```